# Getting Forbidden/Access Denied error from Azure AD Graph Education API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

> I am using Graph education API, want all information about the user
>   profile.
>   Getting below error in response/json objects
>   Forbidden
>   AccessDenied
>   Required claim values are not provided.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserDetails()
        {
            List<User> listUser = new List<User>();
            List<UserRole> userRole = new List<UserRole>();


            string clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");
            string clientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret");


            //var email = User.Identity.Name;

            //AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/LPExamDev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token");
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/LPExamStaging.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token");
            ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", creds);

            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();            
            string url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users";  // Microsoft Education Graph

            //string url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"; // Microsoft Graph // Working fine.
            ////string url = "https://graph.windows.net/LPExamStaging.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6"; 

            // Append the access token for the Graph API to the Authorization header of the request by using the Bearer scheme.
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonResponse = response.ToString();
            bool responseCode = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            //ViewBag.userData = json;

            //SaveAPIData(json);


            if (responseCode)
            {
                SaveAPIData(json);
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant your application `EduRoster.Read.All` permission and click grant admin consent button.

[image]

Login azure portal->click Azure Active Directory->click App registrations(preview)->click your application->click API permissions->add a permission->choose Application permissions

[image]

Then click Grant admin consent button.

[image]

You can decoded your access token by using https://jwt.io/ to check if you have already got that permission.
[image]

Comment: My application registration setting now showing these options. Application type shows "Native"?  It's actually a web app. Application is deployed on one tenant and registered on another. I have access to registered application tenant as admin.

Comment: @RAhulApte Sorry, what do you mean? You should register your app as web app.

Comment: @RAhulApte You can follow my steps to add the permission to your registered application. Just let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Application type setting was changed, back to web app now. I edited and ticked eduroster permissions on the domain and granted admin consent too, still the same error.

Comment: @CaiyiJu Can anyone access all schools information through graph api? I mean, if i create a web app, register it with AD, get client_id, secret, give appropriate permissions then would i be able to do `GET /schools` and get all schools information?

Comment: @Venky Please ask a new question. This will be helpful for others to research.