# How to fix this issue during the login phase of an organisation account using microsoft adal authentication "Need admin approval"

Tags: windows, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an cordova mobile application where it has login phase using *MICROSOFT ADAL*, When I try logging in using organization account I face issue as *Need admin approval* and it says *Application needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant*.

Part of code used:

```
   var authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/adminconsent?clientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/";
                    var resourceUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
                    var clientId = "xyz";

                    var authContext = new $window.Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
                        authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                        .then(function (authResponse) {
                            console.log("New Login")
```

At first I tried using 
`https://login.windows.net/common`
and later tried with this
`https://login.windows.net/common/adminconsentclientID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/`

I've made used *Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) plugin for Apache Cordova apps*

Want the application to gets logged in using organization account.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the error message, you didn't click grant admin consent button after adding the permission. Which develop language are you using? You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code.

Comment: @TonyJu  We are making use of Angular JS.
I've updated the issue check once.

Comment: The authority should be https://login.windows.net/common. And you need to grant admin consent. You can use Azure portal or build the consent URL. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310917/10504999

Comment: FYI we are making use of ```apps.dev.microsoft``` to generate clientId.

Comment: It is recommended to use Azure portal to manage the application. You can switch to Azure portal. You needn't to create a new one. Or just use the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use `https://login.windows.net/common` as the authority.

2.Grant admin consent. Here are two options.

**Use Azure portal.**

You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55646623/10504999).

**Build the consent URL.**

Go to a URL such as https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize?client_id=app-client-id&redirect_uri=encoded-reply-url&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent.

Use your admin account to consent the permissions.

[image]